# Adding Vuforia to an existing Hololens project

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, vuforia

I'm trying to add vuforia to an existing hololens project in unity.
I get this exception when building the app:

**System.TypeInitializationException
  HResult=0x80131534
  Message=The type initializer for 'WinRTBridge.TypeInformation' threw an exception.
  Source=WinRTBridge
  StackTrace:
   at WinRTBridge.TypeInformation..ctor()
Inner Exception 1:
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Vuforia.UnityExtensions, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.**

Using Unity 2017.3.1f1 and the built-in Vuforia plugin 7.0.50

When I'm starting the project from the unity player it does work.
Also, I've succeeded in deploying the vuforia hololens sample project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve that issue by seeing this thread:
https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/1461

apparently there is an issue using vuforia behaviour with the mixed reality camera script.